# Error al crear una tabla en mi base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy tratando de crear una tabla en mi base de datos pero no se cual es el motivo del error que me esta lanzando.

**Código**

```
CREATE TABLE message_chat (
id_chat                     int(255) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
id_user_chat                int(255) NOT NULL,
id_product                  int(255) NOT NULL,
email_user                  varchar(100) NOT NULL,
title_product               varchar(200) NOT NULL,
message_chat                text NOT NULL,
ip_chat                     varchar(190),
browser_chat                varchar(190),
create_at_chat              date,
CONSTRAINT fk_chat_user FOREIGN KEY(id_user_chat) REFERENCES users(id_usuario),
CONSTRAINT fk_chat_email FOREIGN KEY(email_user) REFERENCES users(email),
CONSTRAINT fk_chat_id_product FOREIGN KEY(id_product) REFERENCES product(id_producto),
CONSTRAINT fk_chat_title_product FOREIGN KEY(title_product) REFERENCES product(title)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

**Mensaje de error**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @BetaM se a lo que te refieres y ninguna de las tablas tiene el mismo nombre en las claves foráneas, ya que yo le agrego a los nombre de las foráneas el mismo nombre de la tabla

Comment: De todos modos, como bien sugiere @BetaM, debes mostrar las otras tablas. Este tipo de error suele ocurrir cuando alguna columna en la otra tabla no es del mismo tipo por ejemplo, o si alguna de las tablas no está declarada con el mismo `ENGINE`, o si alguna de las columnas tiene una codificación distinta, etc ... Sin ver las otras tablas no podremos decirte dónde está el problema.

Answer (score 0):

No se si lo que hice esta bien, pero le di solución a mi problema quitando la relación con el titulo de *product*, total no era necesario para mi que este relacionada

```
CREATE TABLE message_chat (
id_chat                     int(255) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
id_user_chat                int(255) NOT NULL,
id_product                  int(255) NOT NULL,
email_user                  varchar(100) NOT NULL,
title_product               varchar(200) NOT NULL,
message_chat                text NOT NULL,
ip_chat                     varchar(190),
browser_chat                varchar(190),
create_at_chat              date,
CONSTRAINT fk_chat_user FOREIGN KEY(id_user_chat) REFERENCES users(id_usuario),
CONSTRAINT fk_chat_email FOREIGN KEY(email_user) REFERENCES users(email),
CONSTRAINT fk_chat_id_product FOREIGN KEY(id_product) REFERENCES product(id_producto)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

De esta manera he logrado solucionar el problema